# Get a vertical slider to float images next to each other (inline) rather than block-style

Tags: views, theming, javascript

I'm working on a Drupal 6 slider that is supposed to scroll through logos (3-4 per row), one row at a time. I can even get the output to sort according to how I'd like it done.

My problem is that the images always display block-style (1 image per row) rather than float next to each other so there are 3-4 per row. I'm sure this is a simple CSS fix somewhere, but as I'm new to Drupal, I cannot figure out what file I'm supposed to edit to make this happen?

If someone has a solution better than manually editing files on the server, I'd be please to here it. Thanks!

Comment: Which theme do you use?

Comment: which module is you used to create slideshow? [Views Slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) ?